# Getting the value of a class after it's populated on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to get the value/text of a a class(.item-title) but the class isn't available right away, it's loaded via angular.  I tried to use window.load to have the page load before trying to get the value but this isn't working, it comes up empty because the class doesn't have a value yet.  Once the page loads then the class does have a value.  Once the page loads I can use the Chrome console to output .item-title just fine. Is there a way to get this function to run once the class(.item-title) is populated?  The item has the same value for an ID so that is an option as well.  THANK YOU!!!

Called by a simple JS reference in :
    /App/lib/angulartics/angulartics-mixpanel.js"

Full contents of angulartics-mixpanel.js:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('angulartics.mixpanel', ['angulartics'])
.config(['$analyticsProvider', function ($analyticsProvider) {

    angulartics.waitForVendorApi('mixpanel', 500, '__loaded', function     (mixpanel) {
        $analyticsProvider.registerPageTrack(function (path) {
            var properties = {
                'Page': $('.item-title').text()
            };
            mixpanel.track("Page Viewed", properties);
        }));
    });

}]);
})(angular);
```

Comment: Why don't you use ng-model?

Comment: Show your HTML. Also where is this code snippet placed?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I've added more of the script.  I was trying to simplify it but that probably made it more confusing.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), either with no delay value since that waits till just about everything else is finished before firing, or with a time delay if need be. Don't forget to inject $timeout into your controller first!

I've modified this post to include the (I think) correct implementation for your module pattern. (More on Dependency Injections [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di))

```
    (function ( angular ) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'angulartics.mixpanel', ['angulartics'] ).config( ['$analyticsProvider', '$timeout', function ( $analyticsProvider, $timeout ) {

        angulartics.waitForVendorApi( 'mixpanel', 500, '__loaded', function ( mixpanel ) {
            $analyticsProvider.registerPageTrack( function ( path ) {
                $timeout( function () {
                    var properties = {
                        'Page': $( '.item-title' ).text()
                    };
                    mixpanel.track( "Page Viewed", properties );
                },1000 );

            } );
        } );

    }] );
   })( angular );
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance, Max!  I'm new to Angular so I'm flying by the seat of my pants.  :-)   I've edited my original example to show more of what I am trying to do.  I'm not sure how to inject $timeout in this example.  I can add $timeout as something like this:

    $timeout($analyticsProvider.registerPageTrack(function (path) {


But how do I inject $timeout?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angulartics or the menthod waitForVendorApi (which seems to have a 500ms delay before the function within is called) but ... that's how I believe you'd use $timeout in your implementation. You might also want to experiment with just increasing the 500ms delay to 1000 or 1500. LMK.